# Blender will no longer save .tga files

Tags: texturing, uv

Recently, and in the middle of a project blender just quit saving .tga UV maps correctly. I did not close blender between the last .tga file that worked and the one that did not work.

When I save the UV layout as tga file I get a file that has NO extention at all (not .tga or anything) so obviously, the computer does not know how to open it or what to do with it. It also has a file size of 0kb instead of the usual 1.83MB.

I am creating skyrim armors, using blender 2.49, python 2.6.2 and can't remember the nifscripts version, but it's the version that goes with 2.49 (and shouldn't affect saving the UV layouts anyway).

As I am unable to save UV layouts, I am unable to create textures for my armors and need to fix this ASAP.

**EDIT:** The *Blender Console* reads as follows:

```
 Imagesize: 800px wiresize: 1px wrap: yes allfaces: yes formage: *.tga 
 target: (folder I've got it set to save to TGA export is running... 
 memory : 625kb 100 of 760 faces completed (repeats until 700 of 760 faces completed)
 ...writing tga...
```

Comment: Try restarting Blender, reinstalling, or resetting user preferences to default.

Comment: I've restarted blender as well as my PC, I hate doing reinstalls due to according to the wiki, i need to install the python, blender and nifscripts in a certain order and would need to uninstall all of them, so I'm saving that as a last ditch effort. How do I change user preferences in blender? Never messed with any prefs on it lol

Comment: There is a key command you press and hold when you start up Blender, I can't remember what it is though . . .

Comment: Can't seem to figure out how to edit my question, did not consider looking at the blender console before now. Says:

Imagesize: 800px
wiresize: 1px
wrap: yes
allfaces: yes
formage: *.tga
target: (folder I've got it set to save to

TGA export is running...
memory : 625kb
100 of 760 faces completed
(repeats until 700 of 760 faces completed)
   ...writing tga...

Comment: thats for the info, I'll google it and try resetting prefs :)

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the same as the startup command, but you can also go to *File > Load Factory Settings* which should update your preferences to the defaults, and possibly solving your issue

Comment: I'm unable to find any info about a command. All I can find on google is to delete the B.blend file which says SHOULD be located in my .blend folder, however, I can find no blender folders in my documents and the only folder inside blender foundation is "blender" but no folder named (DOT)blend

Comment: Will try that now :)

Comment: Ok, used the load factory settings, then saved the tga file, the console was exactly the same however this time at the bottom it says "...finished exporting in 0.7574 sec." but the file is the same. 0 size, no file extension. I tried adding the .tga to the end myself, changed the files icon to the targa icon, but still won't open in photoshop because it's still 0kb.

Comment: reinstall my last hope? :(

Comment: Not knowing more about it, that is what I'd recommend, however that is not guaranteed to fix it. Restoring factory defaults should do it. What settings are there when you export?

Comment: I reinstalled blender only, did not reinstall the pyffi or nifscrips (though they appear to still be working, or at least the option to import nif file is still available) opened my .blend file for the armor I'm working, but still will not save tga file

Comment: These are the Settings that pop up when I click UVs>scripts>save UV face layout. Size: 800 Wire: 1 Wrap selected, all faces selected, object selected, SVG NOT selected, Fill SVD faces selected, edit NOT selected.